# Whatsapp crashes while calling

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

java.lang.Error: signal 11 (Address not mapped to object) at address 0x8 [at libmedia.so:0x5507e (_ZN7android11ClientProxy9interruptEv+0x3)]
    at com.whatsapp.Voip.nativeHandleCallOfferAck(Native Method)
    at com.whatsapp.VoiceService.a(VoiceService.java:404)
    at com.whatsapp.messaging.r.a(r.java:731)
    at com.whatsapp.alb.handleMessage(alb.java:4)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (Address not mapped to object)
 at address 0x8 [at libmedia.so:0x5507e (_ZN7android11ClientProxy9interruptEv+0x3)]
    at system.lib.libmedia_so.0x5507e(android::ClientProxy::interrupt():0x3:0)
    at system.lib.libmedia_so.0x5d71b(android::AudioRecord::stop():0x1e:0)
    at system.lib.libwilhelm_so.0xa1a3(Native Method)
    at system.lib.libwilhelm_so.0x18e13(Native Method)
    at data.app_lib.com_whatsapp_1.libwhatsapp_so.0x8a589(Native Method)
    at data.app_lib.com_whatsapp_1.libwhatsapp_so.0x8a5a3(Native Method)

Comment: Guys please guide me.when i make a call on whats app.application crashes with above error log.

Comment: No. You cannot just dump an error log on us and expect us to fix it for you. Look at WA's docs or help site, not here.